# Make CherryPy exit immediately upon receiving a keyboard interrupt?

Tags: python, multithreading, cherrypy

Is there an easy way of making CherryPy perform an `os._exit(0)` once it gets a `^C` interrupt?

It would normally wait for all the threads to terminate which is **not** useful for debugging as I expect it to shut down immediately.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

See https://cherrypy.readthedocs.org/en/3.3.0/refman/process/plugins/signalhandler.html.

```
handlers = {'SIGTERM': self.bus.exit,
        'SIGHUP': self.handle_SIGHUP,
        'SIGUSR1': self.bus.graceful,
       }
```

are the default handlers; `SIGINT` from `Ctrl-C` isn't there (so I don't know if it's going the same as `SIGTERM` or what) but you could add it with whatever handler you want, including one that calls `sys._exit`.